# Shell script syntax error when trying to activate a virtualenv and execute a python script in it

Tags: python, shell, cron, virtualenv

I want a script that will activate a virtual environment (in both a shell and through cron) and then run the passed script with all arguments IN that virtualenv.

Here's what I have now for prod.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

. $VE_DIR/Production_VE/bin/activate

python $0 "$@"
```

Then I try this:

```
hostname:~$prod.sh myscript.py -c arg1 -fu
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/home/username/prod.sh", line 3
    . $VE_DIR/Production_VE/bin/activate
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I try switching to source:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $VE_DIR/Production_VE/bin/activate

python $0 "$@"
```

And the error changes up, but now:

```
  File "/home/username/prod.sh", line 3
    source $VE_DIR/Production_VE/bin/activate
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For additional context, I want to be able to run this script on both a CentOS 6.5 VPS and Mac OS.

What's wrong with this picture?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created an script similar to you and it run well. I thought it was really strange, you add an issue with it. But when i look at your error :

```
  File "/home/username/prod.sh", line 3
    source $VE_DIR/Production_VE/bin/activate
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It really look like a Python error and not a bash error. You error is that when you do :

```
python $0 "$@"
```

You should remove the $0 because it contain the path of your bash script.

```
python "$@"
```

Comment: Make sure you keep the quotes for `"$@"`, very important. `$@` is quite different from `"$@"` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Answer (score 0):

in your bash script, $0 is "prod.sh", which is not a python script. Change

```
python $0 "$@"
```

to

```
python "$@"
```